# How can I create a customized bit.ly URL via API?

Tags: javascript, url, bit.ly

I have a textbox that takes a name.

I have a bit.ly pro domain: `cnvrt.it`

I want to shorten a users URL but also customize it as such:

```
cnvrt.it/customized_name
```

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's all here in the bit.ly documentation: http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation.  If you have a more specific question about how to use the API, then please clarify.

I haven't tried this myself, but according to [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/bitly-api/msg/a869cc125e399ee2), if you add the keyword parameter to the shorten API call and set it to the desired custom name, it will do what you want.

Comment: Tested this on 2013-08-21 and it seems to not work. Bitly has stated this was removed due to abuse